# How to best setup a recruitment model

Tags: django, django-models

I was just wondering what would be the best setup for a recruitment model in django?

A user can be recruited by just one user, but the user itself could have recruited many other users.

Is it as simple as:

```
class Recruiter(models.Model):
    recruiter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Recruited(models.Model):
    recruited = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)


class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

    recruited_by = models.ForeignKey(Recruiter, blank=True)
    recruited = models.ManyToManyField(Recruited, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()
```

Or is it a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
class Recruiter(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Recruited(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    recruited_by = models.ForeignKey(Recruiter)
```

Since every Recruiter `is` a User and every Recruited `is` a User, but one Recruited `is recruited by` one Recruiter and one Recruiter can `have recruited` 0 to many Recruiteds. In this schema, there is implicit backward relation from Recruiter instance accessed like:

```
 recruiter_instance.recruited_set
```

Just see the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield
If you are using different Django version, you can use version switch - it's on every Django docs page in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Okay! Is it necessary to reference these models inside my "UserProfile" model?

Comment: No, the backwards relation is created implicitly - read the docs I've provided carefully. I assume that `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL == UserProfile`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying for? 
I would do that:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

    recruited_by = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, related_name="recruited")

    objects = UserManager()
```

Are Recruiter and Recruited classes necessaries?

Comment: He might need additional data related to Recruiter and/or Recruited bu just in case he doesn't +1 for your answer.

Comment: How would I get a list of all the people the user has recruited using this setup?

Comment: @Garreth00, `user_profile_instance.recruited` to access the backward relation set - see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488944/how-to-best-setup-a-recruitment-model/17489127#17489127

Comment: `recruiter_instance.recruited` (related_name="recruited" define this variable). See the docs that @ElmoVanKielmo said